# German documents translation to English

Tags: uk, germany, standard-visitor-visas, german-language, translations

I am a student in Germany. I would like to visit the UK as a tourist for a few days. I am not sure where I can get my document translated. Is there any online service which does this?

> Visitor: supporting documents guide
>
> This guidance explains the documents you may need to provide in support of your application to visit the UK.
>
> All documents must be originals and not photocopies. Submission of these documents does not guarantee that your application will be successful and you
>   should bear this in mind when making any bookings.
>
> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office.
>
> Each translated document must contain:
>
> - confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document
> - the date of the translation
> - the translator's full name and signature
> - the translator's contact details

Above section contain the rules for translation. It requires signature and date. So should I go to a lawyer for this?

Can someone give a few hints on this? What is the average cost for translation per page?

Comment: A quick search on Google for 'translation services in Germany' pulls up a list of companies that offer this sort of service. You'd get a better list by searching your local area. You'd have to contact individual companies to find out if they can handle your native language and what they charge.

Comment: @CannonFodder I doubt many translation services in Germany would be unable to handle translation from German to English.

Comment: @phoog Agreed, but as the OP is presumably not German (as then he/she wouldn't need a visa) my guess is that some of the required documents would need to be translated from some other language.

Comment: @CannonFodder the question title is "German documents translation to English"

Comment: yes, I have German documents like my work contract, proof that I am a student in university, my salary slips. I need to translate at least these documents. For bank statement, DB bank people told, we can get an English version on its website and that will be considered as official bank statement.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword to search for is `beglaubigte übersetzung` (add either your city or `online` to the query).

You will find heaps of certified translators. Even those not operating completely online are usually able to receive your documents via mail and provide you a scan of their translation quickly.

This is not necessarily cheap, a few years ago I paid 130€ for translating a four page transcript of records. If you are enrolled in an university, the language service of my university at the time would also have been able to do a certified translation for me (at little or no cost), however at a waiting time beyond my needs.